# Fixed width table with variable width columns

Tags: tables, width, tabulary

What I'm trying to achieve is a fixed width (full width of the page or column) table with variable column widths. Here's what I've got:

```
\usepackage{tabulary}

   % Table Environment
\newenvironment{dndcustomtable}[1]{
  \vspace*{8pt}
  \fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont %Select font
  \rowcolors{1}{bgtan}{commentgreen} % Alternate colors
  \noindent\tabulary{\textwidth}{#1}
}
{
  \endtabulary
  \vspace{8pt plus 1pt}
  \noindent
}

% Usage
\begin{dndcustomtable}{LLL}
lorem ipsum &   foo bar &   baz \\
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum &   foo bar &   baz \\
lorem ipsum &   foo bar &   baz \\
lorem ipsum &   foo bar lorem ipsum&    baz \\
\end{dndcustomtable}
```

What I'm getting:
[image: What I'm getting]

Desired Result:
[image: What I'm trying to get (photoshopped)]

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `tabularx` for that. B.t.w., use `\linewidth` rather than `\textwidth`, they may be different, and usually, it's the former one wants.

Comment: the `\noindent` at the end of the environment looks very odd and will produce spurious results if you have a blank line in the source after the table.